# Creating users for game(reading and parsing CSV file)

Tags: c++, qt, file, parsing, user-interface

So I am working on a planets vs zombies type mock up game for class, and am using Qt Creator GUI with C++. One of the things that we are required to do is, on start-up, the game window will attempt to read two files: "*pvz_levels.csv*" and "*pvz_players.csv*" from a pre-specified home directory.

The *levels* file is of the form **"level:sequence:rows:start:interval:decrement"** and **"sequence"** itself is a comma separated list of the form **(1,1,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,3)** which is the sequence in which zombies appear. If this file does not exist in the directory, the program exits with an error.

The *players* file is of the form **"timestamp:player:level"**; the time of last play, name of player, and last attempted level, respectively. If this file does not exist, the program silently skips this operation and starts as a new player. If it does exist, the file must be read and parsed, and then used in the program for calculations and such.

So, I am having much trouble with reading and parsing these files. Furthermore, we are required to save the user data in these files, and on the next start-up the user should have the option to continue their game by selecting their respective user from a drop-down list. They should also be able to delete any users.

I am proficient enough with c++ basics but this is my first GUI experience and my prof did not go over it in much detail, so I require quite a bit of help with this project.

Thank you to anyone who is able to help!

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the code to an available "csv parser" which stands for "comma separated variable". You need is almost identical, except you use a semi-colon instead of a comma. It seems that by changing one character you parsing is done for you.

You may be able to find a csv parser that accepts the character to be used as the parsing character (I've seen them before).

If you wish I can find a suitable csv parser for your use, but now that you know what you're looking for "csv parser c++ code" it should be a quick Google away.

Also, most csv parsers expect strings to be enclosed to double quotes (") but that is easily modifable.

Comment: hi will this work in the case of the sequence as well, ie. after parsed how will the string look like? also i was able to find a couple parsers but none specifically for Qt, because I am also required to perform the parsing using QString and QFile etc, thank you

Comment: Others are giving specific instructions for using QFile.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Just open the File using `QFile`. Set up a `QTextStream` and use `QTextStream::readLine()` to read all Lines into QStringList. Now use `QString::split()` on the QString saved in the list to get the single values stored in this line. From there you can easily use `QString::to*` functions to cast the values into your desired type.

For saving just reverse the procedure.
Set up a line using: `QString("%1,%2,%3").arg(timestamp).arg(player).arg(level)` and put it into your `QTextStream`. If the stream is connected to a file, this will be written into the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented successfully the CSV reading like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<QFile> csv_worker(new QFile(resource_path));
QTextStream input_csv(csv_worker.get());
QList<QStringList> data
while(!input_csv.atEnd()) 
{       
    //removes the carriage return symbol and splits the elements
    QStringList line = input_csv.readLine().remove(QRegExp("\r")).split(","); //replace here with :
    data << line;
}
csv_worker->close();
```

It reads the complete file, each line generates a QStringList.
For the second element in the QStringList, let's say  (1,1,1,2,3,1,3,1,3,3}, you have to additionally split that in a sub-QStringList, removing then brackets with something like this:

```
QStringList sequence = data[i][1].remove(QRegExp("{")).remove(QRegExp("}")).split(",");
```

Comment: You can use [QString::trimmed()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#trimmed) instead of `str.remove(QRegExp("\r"))`

Comment: yeah that's an alternative!